# scheduler_count in Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sp-blitz

I'm trying to find a scheduler_count for my Azure SQL DB, so that I can get sp_Blitz to run. On all other platforms, scheduler_count can be read from sys.dm_os_sys_info, but this dmv is not available currently.

```
SELECT scheduler_count, * FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info;
```

Do you know of a way to find it?

I also need a (estimate for) cpu_count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately this DMV is not accessible.**

[image]

Adam Machanic has made a user feedback item, you can cast your [vote](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/33864208-sys-dm-os-sys-info-ms-ticks-in-azure-sql-db) to urge Microsoft to make it available.

It has been picked up by Microsoft, and has been under review since  *april 6 2018*.

**You could get your `DTU` count or `CPU` count, depending on your model from a certain reporting interval from the `sys.dm_db_resource_stats` DMV.**

```
SELECT  dtu_limit ,MAX(end_time) as end_time 
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
GROUP BY dtu_limit; -- DTU Model


SELECT  cpu_limit ,MAX(end_time) as end_time
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
GROUP BY cpu_limit; -- VCpu Model
```

**The maximum of 5 Dtu's on my basic tiered database is returned by the query**

```
dtu_limit   end_time
5   2019-03-21 19:17:05.237
```

**And as a result of being on the DTU model, VCpu count will return `NULL`.**

```
cpu_limit   end_time
NULL    2019-03-21 19:17:05.237
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. At https://github.com/HenrikStaunPoulsen/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/issue_1970/HenrikStaunPoulsen you can see how I've put your suggestion to use.  Any suggestions on how to estimate a scheduler_count?